# Interacting with a Service

Tags: android, android-intent, service

In my application, a Service is started when the app begins, and does not stop until the app is closed (I use START_STICKY).  Currently I have different components that need to communicate with the service bind and unbind.  My thought now is why bother to bind and unbind when I could simply make Intents to communicate with the Service.

Is having my components send intents to the Service a better idea then binding if the service is going to be up continuously?  I see the benefit being less complex code because the components will simple create the Intent and call start service

Comment: The only times I can think of that I have utilized binding is when I want the Service and/or Activity have some sort of reliance on the other, or there is a ton of communication happening. It sounds like that isn't the case for you so I would think Intents would work fine.

Comment: If I was to have my components need to react to events in the Service, would it then be a good idea to bind to add them as listeners? I am trying to figure out when I should / shouldn't bind

Comment: have you read "Bound Services" doc?  the case of "local bound service" is particularly interesting

Comment: yes, that is how I learned to bind the component

Comment: In that case it is kind of up to you. You could send out broadcasts for your Activities to listen for and respond to, or you could bind to them and utilize the bind to handle Service communication with your Activity. Binding requires a bit more setup but allows for simpler communication, so I guess it is kind of what you are more comfortable with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really up to you and your needs, as others have noted in the comments.  Using the binder approach, you have a more direct connection with the service which allows you to make what look like direct calls (and in fact are if you are in the same process.)  Using `Intent` to communication means your communication mechanism is more message based and you'd have to deal with different `Intent` payload.  It also incurs some additional overhead because calling `startService()` or `startActivity()` or `sendBroadcast()` all end up going down to the `ActivityManagerService` running in system_server.  Another alternative could be to use `Intent` to setup the connection between the `Service` and `Activity` and have both use a `Messenger` to send messages back and forth.  It's similar to the pure `Intent` mechanism, but once the `Messenger` objects are exchanged there's no more involvement from `ActivityManagerService`.

Comment: thank you for your input, I will definitely check out the messenger and ActivityManagerService class more to get a better idea of whats going on

Comment: Glad to help.  Note that you won't find much regarding the `ActivityManagerService` as far as how this works.  The `Context` objects when calling start/stop service, start activity, etc. all communication with the activity manager service to do what you're requesting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sending data to a service in an intent and processing the intent in the onStartCommand or OnBind is very straight forward method.  The problem is how does the service communicate back to the activity|fragment.

The messenger service has one advantage it can send a copy of every outgoing message to all of the clients that are bound to the service and you can pass the same Bundle of data that you would in an Intent.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger

The above example can be modified to send bundles of data back and forth with the message.